# Looping component tag element in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this logic in my Angular component

```
 ngOnInit() {
 for (const pckg of this._newrequestapi.request_parameters.Packages.split(',')) {
  this.package_route = ''.concat('<app-', pckg , '></app-' , pckg , '>');
  this.pckg_route_array.push(this.package_route);
}
console.log(this.pckg_route_array) ;
```

}

The above logic basically defines an array that contains some other components tag element .
So lets say i have two components cp-abc and cp-xyz the array will contain these valyes `["<cp-abc></cp-abc>","<cp-xyz></cp-xyz>"]`

in my template i am trying to loop through this array to render each component tag element

```
<div *ngFor=
   "let pckg_route of pckg_route_array;">{{pckg_route}}
</div>
```

On my html page i just see these two lines instead of the components getting redered

```
<cp-abc></cp-abc>
<cp-xyz></cp-xyz>
```

Angualar 6 doesnt not allow innerHTML attribute so cant use that . Any suggestions here .

Comment: It seems like you are trying to dynamically load components? It doesn't work like this -- angular will treat those strings as just strings. Research dynamic component loading, it is a complex topic and your current code is not ever going to get the job done. This simply is not how it is done.

Comment: Thanks Chris . From what i have understood . i think dynamic component loading is the solution . it is indeed a complex topic that i need to get a grasp on . Thanks for your help .